# Why I cannot retrieve the value from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I able to build apk and i have LoginActivity.java, SignupActivity.java, StoreNameAndType.java with User.java, RetrieveDataActivity.java.

I also able to deployed the apk into my android phone and the apps working perfect with layout loginactivity, signupactivity, storenameandtypeactivity.

The layout of retrieveDataActivity is after i done login in the login layout. But then when it move to the layout retrievedataactivity, it will display the layout UI less than 10sec and it crash.

Why I cannot retrieve the bunch of data from user at my firebase? I follow the tutorial at YouTube but the layout crash. It something wrong on my code?

I log in as user-d (**3wgmOhWlUUcyoBQXKZWnhw3K7Ik2**).

Here my database tree. I want to retrieve all information from the user-id (**yKlWu19vhqQXfL2tDlBNfMSduMe2**).

```
{
  "3wgmOhWlUUcyoBQXKZWnhw3K7Ik2" : {
      "name" : "MAMA",
      "type" : "P"
  },
  "yKlWu19vhqQXfL2tDlBNfMSduMe2" : {
      "location" : {
          "latitude" : 3.0537728,
          "longitude" : 101.4826099
      },
      "name" : "AYAH NAN",
      "type" : "D"
  }
}
```

Here my rules

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Here my RetrivedataActivity.java

```
public class RetrieveDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
  ValueEventListener {

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference, mNameReference, 
      mTypeReference, mLocationReference, mLatReference, mLongReference;
    private TextView mNameView, mTypeView, mLatView, mLongView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrievedata);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("yKlWu19vhqQXfL2tDlBNfMSduMe2");
    mNameReference = databaseReference.child("name");
    mTypeReference = databaseReference.child("type");
    mLocationReference = databaseReference.child("location");
    mLatReference = mLocationReference.child("latitude");
    mLongReference = mLocationReference.child("longitude");
    mNameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    mTypeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewType);
    mLatView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLat);
    mLongView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLong);

}

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)!=null)
    {
        String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

        if(key.equals("name"))
        {
            String name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mNameView.setText(name);

        }else if(key.equals("type"))
        {
            String type = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mTypeView.setText(type);

        }else if(key.equals("latitude"))
        {

            String lat = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mLatView.setText(lat);

        }else if(key.equals("longitude"))
        {

            String log = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mLongView.setText(log);

        }


    }

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mNameReference.addValueEventListener(this);
    mTypeReference.addValueEventListener(this);
    mLatReference.addValueEventListener(this);
    mLongReference.addValueEventListener(this);

}
}
```

Comment: Is your app crashing? If so, please edit your question to include the full stack trace that shows in logcat.

Comment: u means all code?

Comment: You didn't describe the problem you're having. If you're getting a crash or an error message, include the stack trace of that error in your question. It will be printed in the logcat window of Android Studio. If something just isn't working as expected, explain what you see. It would also be helpful to see you database's security rules.

Comment: Ok I describe more. it is ok sir?

Comment: This link shows you where to find the stack trace in Android Studio. The error message should help you to understand the problem, and is something you should include in your question for others to help you. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces.html

Comment: I find my log.cat. Its quite long. How do i paste it in here?

Comment: Edit your question and paste it. Have in mind that we don't need the entire logcat. Only the part where the exception has been thrown.